# Who will put on last of the grid if many drivers get back grid penalty in F1?

Tags: rules, formula-1

At the 2022 Belgian Grand Prix, six drivers are due to start at the back of the grid due to [power unit penalties](https://www.skysports.com/f1/news/12433/12681960/belgian-gp-max-verstappen-and-charles-leclerc-set-for-back-of-the-grid-starts-after-engine-penalties). So, these drivers will occupy places P15 to P20 on the grid.

How is it determined which driver will be in P15 and which driver will be in P20 if all six drivers got the penalty simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

**They will be ordered by their qualifying position**

From the [Sporting Regulations](https://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/formula_1_-_sporting_regulations_-_2022_-_iss_4_-_2022-02-18.pdf), for race weekends *without* a Sprint Race:

> **42.3**
>
> (d) Once the grid has been established in accordance with Article 42a), 42b) and 42c), grid penalties for any driver required to start the race from the back of the grid after incurring a penalty under Article 28.3) will be applied.
>
> - i) If more than one (1) driver is required to start the race from the back of the grid they will be arranged in qualifying order.
>
> Any driver who incurs a penalty under in accordance with Article 28.3) or Article 29) will take precedence over any driver whose qualifying practice times have been deleted for any reason.

And, in the case that multiple drivers do not set a qualifying time at all:

> If more than one (1) driver falls into a single category in Article 42.3b) or Article 42.3e) above they will be arranged on the grid in the order they were classified in the previous period of the qualifying practice session or, in the case of Q1, the order they were classified in P3.

---

For weekends *with* a Sprint Race, the rules are mostly the same, in that the drivers will be placed in relation to their finishing place in the Sprint Race. However, if they do not participate in the Sprint Race, then it goes back to the Sprint Qualifying placing.

> **41.4**
>
> [...]
>
> If more than one driver falls into a single category in b) or e) above they will be arranged on the grid in the order they were classified in the sprint session or, in the order they were classified in the qualifying practice session.

And, although not expressly stated, I imagine that if the drivers did not participate in Sprint qualifying, then it would go by the P1 standings, similar to the non-sprint race weekends.